# how can i send jframe as argument to a method of another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to send object of **J-frame** to method of another class from Action Listener.so that the content of the called method are in same frame. but i m unable to get that method in same frame.help please..

```
     public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents(this);
}                      
public void initComponents(NewJFrame ob) {

    scrollbar1 = new java.awt.Scrollbar();
    jScrollBar1 = new javax.swing.JScrollBar(); //all the GUI**inside this method i created button(jMenuItem2) and called method of another class in action listener as shown below**   

jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {
        MenuExp obb=new MenuExp();
       // System.out.println(arg.getSource().getClass());
        obb.cross(ob);
         } });
  }
public class MewExp{
public void cross(NewJFrame obbb)
{
    //final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Demo");
    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();

    JButton btnCalendar = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\vishnu\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\imazer\\src\\imazer\\kick.jpg"));
    btnCalendar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(, "Calendar clicked");
        }
    });
    toolbar.add(btnCalendar);
   // setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    obbb.getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //setSize(200, 500);
    //setVisible(true);
    //System.out.print(obbb);

    obbb.add(toolbar);
   // setVisible(true);
   // obbb.pack();

}
```

Comment: what did you try so far? show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `Menu` is another class

and that class has method `changeContent(JFrame sameFrame)`

then

```
     Menu menu=new Menu();
     menu.changeContent(this);
```

will do the job for you.

Comment: it's not working.i need contents of `changeContent` in same frame but the method is opening a new frame

Comment: post your changeContent() method